# Hibernate : Join Table with composite key with a constant value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In hibernate, I have a parent table and a child with oneToOne relation.

The child table has a composite key.

One of the key (CODE_TYPE_ENTITE) is a constant value for the parent table.
How can I declare that without using an sql field with default value in the parent table ?

Edit : CODE_TYPE_ENTITE is not a constant in the child table ADRESSE_REF. But the relationship exists only with CODE_TYPE_ENTITE == 'CINT'

The code below is working but I'm not very happy of it...

Table 1 :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CABINET_INTERMEDIAIRE")
public class CabinetIntermediaire implements Serializable {
    private String codeCabinet;
    private AdresseRef adresseRef;
    private String codeTypeEntite;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODE_CABINET")
    public String getCodeCabinet() {...}

    public void setCodeCabinet(String codeCabinet) {...}

    @Basic
    @Column(name= "CODE_TYPE_ENTITE")
    public String getCodeTypeEntite() {...}

    public void setCodeTypeEntite(String codeTypeEntite) {...}

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_CABINET", referencedColumnName = "CODE_ENTITE", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name= "CODE_TYPE_ENTITE", referencedColumnName = "CODE_TYPE_ENTITE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    public AdresseRef getAdresseRef() {...}

    public void setAdresseRef(AdresseRef adresseRef) {...}
}
```

Table 2 :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADRESSE_REF", schema = "EXTRANET", catalog = "")
@IdClass(AdresseRefPK.class)
public class AdresseRef implements Serializable{
    private String codeTypeEntite;
    private String codeEntite;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODE_TYPE_ENTITE")
    public String getCodeTypeEntite() {...}

    public void setCodeTypeEntite(String codeTypeEntite) {...}

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODE_ENTITE")
    public String getCodeEntite() {...}

    public void setCodeEntite(String codeEntite) {...}
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you show a sample of your data from those two tables (limited to the mentioned columns)? If `CODE_ENTITE` is **always** constant (eg. "ABC") then why do you have it anyway? Or do you mean that the relationship only exists if `CODE_ENTITE` == "ABC"?, but you also have other values in `ADRESSE_REF` that are not related to `CABINET_INTERMEDIAIRE`?

Comment: @AdamMichalik You're right ! CODE_TYPE_ENTITE is not a constant in ADRESSE_REF but, as you say, the relationship between CABINET_INTERMEDIAIRE and ADRESSE_REF exists only if CODE_TYPE_ENTITE == 'CINT'.